# Having Trouble Generating A Simple Select Dropdrown In CakePHP 2.0

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, formhelper

I'm pretty sure I don't have this problem in Cake 1.3, but:

I have a form input based on an is_live db field (containing 1 or 0 as its value).

The following creates a correctly populated checkbox:

```
echo $this->Form->input('is_live', array('label'=>'Status'));
```

However, the following does not seem to create a correctly populated dropdown (the first option is always selected, even though selecting an item and submitted the form does update correctly):

```
echo $this->Form->input('is_live', array(
    'label'=>'Status', 'type'=>'select' , 'options'=>array(1=>'Live', 0=>'Pending')
));
```

Is there anything simple I can do to make the dropdown populate based on the value of is_live in CakePHP 2.0?  Or is there a workaround?

Comment: if my answer is not good enough, or that you have found a better solution please indicate. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with using 1 and 0 before.

My solution is to use the following

```
$options = array(1=> 'Live', 0=>'Pending');

echo $this->Form->input('YourModel.is_live',
    array(
        'options' => $options, 
        'label' => 'Status', 
        'selected' => intval($defaultValue), // make sure you set a default value
    )
);
```

Answer (score -1):

Can you change the content length of that field? If you can, change it to 2. This will get around the problem.

```
ALTER TABLE `your_table` CHANGE `is_live` `is_live` TINYINT(2)  NULL  DEFAULT NULL;
```

Comment: a boolean (tinyint 1) is just fine, as well. I think his problem lies somewhere else.

Comment: Hello @mark! This solution works for me but obviously has a side effect if you're using a checkbox elsewhere in the application.

Comment: Intriguing suggestion - what's the reasoning behind making such a change?

Comment: @thesunneversets did it work for you? I can see it's been down voted but it works for me using your posted code.